# redis_fdw on rds postgres

Tags: postgresql, redis, amazon-rds, rds, postgres-fdw

Running create extension redis_fdw gives below error. Currently is there any alternative way to create foreign data wrapper for redis and achieve similar goals as [this project](https://github.com/pg-redis-fdw/redis_fdw) on RDS ?

```
Extension "redis_fdw" is not supported by Amazon RDS
```

Answer (score 0):

redis-fdw extension need it's native c libs installed on your servers, this is not allowed on amazon rds, you should use this in amazon ecs server, install postgresql and redis-fdw by yourself